# How to name iOS launch icons for a universal app?

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm

This may be a trivial question, but I can't seem to find a concise answer on how to appropriately name (and what dimensions to use) for the iOS launch icons?

Note I am **not** using Xcode but rather am porting a LibGDX game over to iOS via RoboVM.  This is what my iOS **/data/** folder looks like right now:

[image]

I think I have all of the "Default" launch images set properly, but I'm not sure about the launch icons.  (All of this confusion is really coming from the fact that there is scarce info about the new iPhone 6 and 6 Plus.)

**So basically, what launch icon files are wrong and/or are missing?**

Oh, also in my **plist.xml** file, this is what I have:

[image]

If I add more launch icon images, would I need to change anything here?

(I'm new to iOS development if it isn't painfully obvious yet.)

Comment: This is made much easier by enabling image assets for the app icons and launch images. No need to worry about specific names or confusion about what sizes anything needs to be and it's easy to see which images may be missing.

Comment: @rmaddy Not sure what you mean by enabling image assets. Is that an Xcode thing? I mentioned I'm not using Xcode.

Comment: In Xcode, view the General tab of your main target. Next to the "App Icons Source", click the button to use assets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my libGDX ios project, I have the following icons in my `ios/resources` folder (*not* in the data folder):

`Icon-40.png
Icon-40@2x.png
Icon-60.png
Icon-60@2x.png
Icon-72.png
Icon-72@2x.png
Icon-76.png
Icon-76@2x.png
Icon-Small-50.png
Icon-Small-50@2x.png
Icon-Small.png
Icon-Small@2x.png
Icon.png
Icon@2x.png`

And then in my `Info.plist.xml` file I have:

`<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>Icon</string>
                <string>Icon-40</string>
                <string>Icon-60</string>
                <string>Icon-72</string>
                <string>Icon-76</string>
                <string>Icon-Small</string>
                <string>Icon-Small-50</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
           <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>`

This seems to work as desired.  And, since I'm here and these also took a while to work out, here are the launch images, including the new iPhone 6 and 6+ which it seems are needed to allow native screen resolution support on those devices:

`Default-375w-667h@2x.png
Default-414w-736h@3x.png
Default-568h@2x.png
Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
Default-Landscape~ipad.png
Default.png
Default@2x.png
Default@2x~ipad.png
Default~ipad.png`

As far as I can tell, there are no corresponding Plist entries needed for these.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for, I eventually found it on my own.  This is the perfect answer though!

Answer (score 0):

See section "Icons for Universal Apps" of the following document:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html

They follow the format Icon-"size".

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that page, it's not very clear on what icon is used for what (for example, I only see "home screen on iPad" and "Home screen on iPhone/iPod Touch") - very generic.

Unless the icons needed for an app on an iPhone 4s and an iPhone 6 Plus are the same?

Answer (score 0):

There is now a dedicated wiki page to how to define your icon when you submit your app for iOS.

It´s available here:

https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm/wiki/Howto-Create-an-Asset-Catalog-for-XCode-9-Appstore-Submission%3F

Since xCode 9 you need to define an asset catalog